# Create probability distribution function from given probalbilty

Tags: python, random, probability, distribution

I would like to have a program that calls a random funtcion which gives either 0,1,2 as result for a defined number of times and counts the result for each run.
With using the random.randrange(0,3) I get an equal distribution.

How can I get a distribution with the following probability.

> 0: 0.4633
>
> 1: 0.3147
>
> 2: 0.2218

These numbers are variables that I calculated in a different function and they change after I run the function again.

```
import random

zeros = 0
ones = 0
twos = 0

for i in range(10000):
    a = random.randrange(0,3)

    if a == 0:
        zeros = zeros + 1
    if a == 1:
        ones = ones + 1
    if a == 2:
        twos  = twos + 1


print "zeros = ", zeros
print "ones = ", ones
print "twos = ", twos
```

> zeros =  3345
>
> ones =  3326
>
> twos =  3329

Wanted:

> zeros =  4633
>
> ones =  3147
>
> twos =  2218

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Soooo you want a random distribution to _not_ be random? What is your question? Are you surprised that the counts change on each run?

Comment: You realize that these "probabilities" don't sum to 1.0?  Q.E.D., they're not probabilities.  Also, you shouldn't expect to get the exact same results on each trial, just as you wouldn't expect the same number of 6's out of 100 rolls of a 6-sided die if you repeat the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand the question but if you have the distribution you want then you can just create a list that matches that distribution:

```
N = 10
zeros = int(N * 0.4633)
ones = int(N * 0.3147)
twos = N - zeros - ones
l = [0] * zeros + [1] * ones + [2] * twos
```

If you want it to look more "natural" you can shuffle the list :D

```
random.shuffle(l)
```

Will give you a nice list with your distribution:

> [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2]

Answer (score 1):

Increase your range for the randomization and assign more or less results to each of the outcomes to change the bias.

```
a = random.randrange(0,9998)

if 0<=a<=4632:
    zeros = zeros + 1
if 4643<=a<=7790:
    ones = ones + 1
if 7791<=a<=9998:
    twos  = twos + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_my_rand()
  r = random.randrange(1,10000)
  if r <= 4633:
    return 0
  elif r <= 4633 + 3147:
    return 1
  else:
    return 2
```